# .forEach on array with objects won't run

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

So right now I'm developing a system where students can put in their marks in a form, which will run a function, which puts all the marks inside an array as an object.

Like: `{english_period1: 10, english_period2: 7}` < Example

But, if I want to run a array.prototype.forEach to do something with the marks inside the array. It returns absolutely nothing. The .forEach won't even run.

This is the script:

```
// Make new variable which will store the marks
let allMarks = [];

document.querySelector("#marks").addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  //Execute for each input
  for(let i = 0; i < e.srcElement.length-1; i++){
    // Assign name and value
    const name = e.srcElement[i].name;
    const value = e.srcElement[i].value;

    //Check if value is a mark (number)
    if(value % 1 == 0 && value <= 10){
      //Assign mark
      allMarks[name] = value;
    }else{
      //Value is not a mark, check if it's a O, V or G
      if(value == "O" || value == "V" || value == "G"){
        allMarks[name] = value;
      }else{
        console.log("Niet toegestaan");
      }
    }
  }

  allMarks.forEach(mark => {
    console.log("hello world");
  });

},false);
```

What it does is:

1. After the user has put in its marks and clicks and submits the form
2. Go through all the inputs in the form and put the name plus value as an object in the array.
3. Go over each thing inside the array and print "hello world" in the console.

The goal of the script is to calculate the averages of the students marks and check them against some rules to see if they pass the schoolyear.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't it possible to use the array.prototype.forEach over an an array which contains objects? How could I optimize this piece of code?

Thanks in advance!

### **ANSWER**

Instead of using: `allMarks[name] = value` which won't add an item to the array `allMarks = []`. Using `allMarks.push({name: name, value: value});` will do the trick. Because now it'll add an item in the array ( the object ) and thus the forEach can loop through each item and get it's values like an ordinary object.

Special thanks to: @mhodges

### **LONG ANSWER**

So after debugging, writing more of the script I came to the conclusion that using an object as some suggested in the answers below is a better, more beautiful option.

It is possible to dynamically add keys to an object using `objectName[variableName]`. With the use of `Object.keys(objectName)` you can throw the keys in an array and loop over the keys. It'll result (in my case) in a more beautiful data structure:

Instead of: `[{field: "English", period: "period_1", mark: "7.5"}]`
This will return:

```
"English": {
 "period_1": 7.5,
 "period_2": 6.4
}
```

Comment: I don't think `allMarks[name] = value` is doing what you think it is. You are setting properties on the array, rather than populating the array with values - hence why `.forEach()` is not iterating -- there are no items in the array. Try using `allMarks.push(value)` instead, and see if that works for you

Comment: Side note, `allMarks` would be an array of strings, not an array of objects.

Comment: Another side note: This code functions but not in the way desired. This: `allMarks[name] = value` will create/overwrite an Object property with the key equal the value of the contents of the `name` variable and a value equal to the value of the `value` variable. This object property will be placed into the Array Object named `allMarks` - but doesn't add an array element.  This is easily verified: `console.log(allMarks[name]);`as the last line of the `for()` loop.

Comment: Thank you @mhodges ! It works! Instead of doing `allMarks[name] = value;` which does something I still not understand. Doing `allMarks.push({name: name, value: value});` works. Because now I can iterate over each item in the array and get it's name and value. 

Exactly what I want, but I would rather like an object so I can type: `english_period1.value` for example. Couldn't figure that out, so this was the more understandable option for me. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's a bit difficult to tell what exactly you're trying to do here. If you *need* `allMarks` to be an array, then you'll need to add each individual `mark` to the `allMarks` array, like the below:

```
// Make new variable which will store the marks
let allMarks = [];

document.querySelector("#marks").addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  //Execute for each input
  for(let i = 0; i < e.srcElement.length-1; i++){
    // Assign name and value
    const name = e.srcElement[i].name;
    const value = e.srcElement[i].value;
    // <-- create new mark object -->
    const newMark = {name: value}

    //Check if value is a mark (number)
    if(value % 1 == 0 && value <= 10){
      //Assign mark
      //<-- instead of allMarks[name] = value; -->
      //<-- you need to add the newMark to the allMarks array -->
      allMarks.push(newMark);
    }else{
      //Value is not a mark, check if it's a O, V or G
      if(value == "O" || value == "V" || value == "G"){
        //<-- same thing here -->
        allMarks.push(newMark);
      }else{
        console.log("Niet toegestaan");
      }
    }
  }

  allMarks.forEach(mark => {
    console.log("hello world");
  });

},false);
```

However you could instead make `allMarks` an object and then set each individual `mark` as a key, value pair to that object. You will still be able to loop through the key, value pairs in an object, but you won't be able to use `.forEach`.

Which would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

Your `allMarks[name] = value` turns `allMarks` array into array with literal properties(with object behavior), `.forEach()` wouldn't be run with this. You can use allMarks as object:

```
let allMarksKeys = Object.keys(allMarks); 
allMarksKeys.forEach(key => // for example use allmarks[key] to access object elements)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

forEach will work on Arrays, but array index should be numeric(integer value).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler if you create as an object, rather than an array.

eg.

```
var allMarks = {};
```

and inside you can use

```
var marks;
marks.name = name;
marks.value = value;
allMarks.push(marks);
```

then you can use

```
allMarks.forEach(function(mark){
  console.log(mark.name);
  console.log(mark.value);
});
```

Comment: `.forEach` is not a default property of JS objects.

Comment: Neither is `.push()`

Comment: That was my original problem with using an object, both are not a default for objects. And thus harder to safe all the inputs ( which are a lot haha ).